# ec2 create-image will it backup attached ebs volumes?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, snapshot, amazon-ami

```
$aws ec2 create-image --instance-id xxx --name yyy --description "zzzz" --no-reboot
```

This created AMI image of EC2 instance but did not created extra attached volume's snapshot !

So is there any method to backup EBS volumes at time of creating image ? 
or we have to create volume snapshot separately using

```
$ec2-create-snapshot i-xxxx
```

Comment: does [ec2-bundle-vol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-bundle-vol.html) do what you want?

Comment: Here is script which will find all instance's id within a specified VPC and will create AMI backup for each instance ! 
 #!/bin/bash
 #Script to Automate AMI backup
echo "----------------------------------\n   `date`   \n----------------------------------"
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxx |   awk '{ print $8 }' | sort -n   | grep  "i-" > /tmp/instanceid.txt
echo "Starting the Daily AMI creation: "
 #To create AMI of from instance-id

Comment: for i in $(cat /tmp/instanceid.txt); do
        echo "Creating AMI for Instance id $i ......."
echo "instance-`date +%d%b%y`-$i" > /tmp/aminame.txt
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $i --name "`cat /tmp/aminame.txt`" --description "This is created by ami-backup.sh" --no-reboot | grep -ir ami | awk '{print $4}' > /tmp/amiID.txt
echo  "AMI Name is: `cat /tmp/aminame.txt`\n"
done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional EBS volumes will be included within the AMI, I think that the only limitation is that the AMI excludes the volumes mounted under:

```
/sys
/proc
/dev
/media
/mnt
```

so just mount your volumes somewhere else and any AMI should include all your volumes as well

Comment: As AMI are compressed can I know what is the compression ratio ?

Comment: I guess you ask this to know how would it cost to store your AMIs? here is a link that explains it pretty well:http://www.n2ws.com/blog/how-to-estimate-your-aws-ebs-volumes-snapshot-costs-%E2%80%93-part-2.html. Please note that the snapshot mechanism is incremental, which means that each time you snapshot a volume, it will store only the diff between the previous snapshot and the current one. Thus only the first snapshot is "costly", taking additional snapshot costs almost nothing. But anyway, it does not cost a lot to perform AMI

Comment: i took ami backup with aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $i --name "cat /tmp/aminame.txt" --description "This is created by ami-backup.sh" --no-reboot .....But it created volume snapshoot  which was mounted under /mnt which contradicts according to you ... Additional EBS volumes will be included within the AMI, I think that the only limitation is that the AMI excludes the volumes mounted under: /mnt

Comment: it depends if you use an instance store backed instance or an EBS backed instance. In an EBS backed instance, all volumes attached will be included within your AMI. In a instance store, you will have exclusions as stated above